# When using Talix's power in a two player game, do you return one or both cards to the turn deck?

Tags: aeons-end

Talix's, available on [Aeon's End: The New Age](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/270633/aeons-end-new-age), power reads:

> Destroy two sparks in hand. If you do, shuffle your turn order card into the turn order deck. **OR** Gravehold gains 5 life.

If you are playing a 2 player game, each player has two turn order cards. Then, if you use his first power on your second turn that round (meaning both your turn order cards are in the discard pile) do you place both your turn order cards into the pile or just one?

While the wording on the power seems to indicate it is a single one, it also reads like you just have one "your turn order card". In a two-player game, you have two, so it might make sense to move both back? Is there an official answer?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no official answer on this, nonetheless, it's the last turn order card, as in, the active one. You've got a similar ability with Lash, he only gets one card. If you're playing a 3 player game, and got the wildcard to trigger your turn, I'd say you must put *this* one in the turn order, with no forced play on draw.